# Conditional probabilities in a binary matrix given a pair of values as the condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements, probability

My data comes from a multiple-choice question where respondents could choose more than one selection (the five selections are different roles they held, such as Role1 is a participant on the IT Committee, or Role2 is a participant on the Budget Committee, etc.).  I converted the roles into binary variables where a "1" indicates the respondent selected that role and a "0" indicates they did not select it.

Here is sample data:

```
structure(list(Role1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), Role2 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1), Role3 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), Role4 = c(0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), Role5 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Using the `bindata` package, its `condprob` function calculates the probability that a respondent held any of the roles given that they held another role.

```
library(bindata)
# Returns a matrix containing the conditional probabilities, and converts the matrix to a data frame
condlTable.df <- as.data.frame(condprob(SOdata))
```

My programming question: How can R take any random pair of roles and calculate the conditional probability of any of the other roles?  For example, if a respondent selected Role1 and Role2, a pair of roles, what is the probability that they also selected Role3, or Role4, or Role5?  The ideal output would be like the output of `condprob` but for pairs of selections.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Would the prop.table function give you what you need?

For example:

`prop.table(condlTable.df)`

This gives you the proportions by row:

           `Role1      Role2      Role3      Role4       Role5
Role1 0.07097829 0.05977119 0.02241420 0.01867850 0.007471399
Role2 0.07097829 0.07097829 0.01774457 0.01330843 0.008872286
Role3 0.06083853 0.04055902 0.07097829 0.02027951 0.020279510
Role4 0.07097829 0.04258697 0.02839131 0.07097829 0.000000000
Role5 0.04731886 0.04731886 0.04731886 0.00000000 0.070978286`

adding CondlTable.df per my comment/question below.

          `Role1     Role2     Role3     Role4     Role5
Role1 1.0000000 0.8421053 0.3157895 0.2631579 0.1052632
Role2 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.2500000 0.1875000 0.1250000
Role3 0.8571429 0.5714286 1.0000000 0.2857143 0.2857143
Role4 1.0000000 0.6000000 0.4000000 1.0000000 0.0000000
Role5 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.0000000 1.0000000`

Here is your original data:

```
   Role1 Role2 Role3 Role4 Role5
1      1     0     1     0     0
2      1     1     0     1     0
3      1     1     0     0     0
4      1     1     0     1     0
5      1     1     0     0     0
6      1     0     1     1     0
7      1     1     0     0     0
8      1     1     0     0     1
9      1     1     0     0     0
10     1     1     1     0     0
11     1     1     0     0     0
12     1     0     0     1     0
13     1     1     1     0     0
14     1     1     0     0     0
15     1     1     0     0     0
16     1     1     0     0     0
17     1     1     1     1     0
18     1     1     0     0     0
19     0     0     1     0     1
20     1     1     1     0     1
```

Comment: I don't think so.  If someone selected Role3 and Role4, what is the probability that they also chose Role5, as an example?

Comment: So you are looking for:
P(Role5|(Role3 AND Role 4) - likelihood of choosing Role 5 given they have already chosen Role 3 AND Role 4?

Also, I'm confused by your condlTable.df. In looking at it, you have several non-diagonal "1.00" Values. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, to the first question, but I would like to extend the analysis to any pairs of roles,  And, there are some 1.00 values other than on the diagonals because the two roles were always checked at the same time.  E.g., everyone who held a role for recruitment also held a role for evaluation of personnel.